# can't copy static web files with intellij idea

Tags: maven, jsf, intellij-idea

It copies .class files and libs but It doesn't copies config files like web.xml, faces-config.xml and static xhtml files.I added webapp directory as source folder but nothing happens. I added some screenshots from my project. Do I need to do something else?

[image: My Project Structure]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The webappo folder shouldn't be a source folder. You don't want its content to be part of the classpath. Where do you want IntelliJ to copy these files, and why?

Comment: @JBNizet I excluded webapp. Intellij doesn't copy index.xhtml file or any other config files to "/MavenProject/out/artifacts/MavenProject/". Actually Intellij doesn't do anything with these files. When I run the application I couldn't see my index file.

Comment: Describe how you run your application, and how you determine that you can't see your index file.

Comment: @JBNizet Have you ever used Intellij? Intellij uses artifacts. I added as screenshot. I am using Tomcat as application server.